# Why are two incompatible projections used together in OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers-2, coordinate-system

While going through the examples in OpenLayers, I notice several examples with the following code:

```
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map_element',{
 ...               
 units: 'm',
 projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913'),
 displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
});
```

My understanding is that the code:

```
projection: new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913')
```

displays a square-shaped map using a Spherical Mercator projection, and that the code:

```
displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
```

allows map controls such as the mouse to read from an ellipsoidal projection.

Notwithstanding the differences in units used (the former is in metres while the latter is in degrees), these two projections are totally incompatible since the points on these projections do not really match even if converted to the same unit.

So my question is: Why are these two projections being used together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [OpenLayers Beginner's guide](http://www.packtpub.com/openlayers-2-1-javascript-web-mapping-library-beginners-guide/book), displayProjection is

> ... a property that is used mainly by controls which show
>   coordinate information. By  setting this property on the map object,
>   any control that has a  displayProjection  property will be set to
>   this value. Controls, such as the MousePosition  control, can display 
>   coordinates in the displayProjection. **So, your map could be in a
>   different projection  than what you wish to display the coordinates
>   in.** However, to use a displayProjection  other than EPSG:4326 or
>   EPSG:900913, Proj4js must be included on your page. **This property
>   comes in very handy if, for instance, your map is in a spherical
>   Mercator  projection (i.e., EPSG:900913), but you might wish to
>   display coordinates in another  projection, like EPSG:4326 (to display
>   lon/lat coordinates).**

As for your concern that

> Notwithstanding the differences in units used (the former is in metres
>   while the latter is in degrees), these two projections are totally
>   incompatible since the points on these projections do not really match
>   even if converted to the same unit.

If they're totally incompatible then none of those mashups would work would they? They wouldn't overlay at all. Fortunately, we can do [coordinate transformations](http://kartoweb.itc.nl/geometrics/coordinate%20transformations/coordtrans.html) and that's why it works. The two projections are not incompatible. You can transform coordinates from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:90093 and vice versa.

Comment: Can I take it that there is some kind of transformation going on from projection to display projection?

Comment: Yes.  `projection` refers to the map's actual projection whereas the `displayProjection` refers to the projection of the coordinates that are displayed. In your example, the map has EPSG:900913 coordinates but OpenLayers converts them to EPSG:4326 for display.